# Reactive summarize function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have to define different summarize formulas given an input in a shiny application. In this case, the input is hp. The problem is that hp has 22 unique values. I don't think writing 22 if clauses is a good idea. Is there an alternative?

```
output$stats <- renderTable({


if(input$hp == 52){
mtcars %>%
group_by_(input$cyl) %>%
summarize(formula0 = carb/100,
          formula1 = am*vs)

}

else if(input$hp == 62){
mtcars %>%
group_by_(input$cyl) %>%
summarize(formula2 = gear/carb,
          formula3 = am/vs) 

}
else if(input$hp == 65){

mtcars %>%
group_by_(input$cyl) %>%
summarize(formula4 = qsec + carb,
          formula5 = drat/disp) 

}
else
{

df_subset() %>%
group_by_(input$cyl) %>%
summarize(formula6 = mpg/10,
          formula7 = disp^2) ) 

}


})
```

Comment: Have a look at `switch()`

Comment: @BigDataScientist I'm trying to build something with switch and non-standard evaluation. I'll post it if it works